# Is it a quick way/shortcut to get out of parentheses in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say I want to code:

```
if(x == 1) {
   ...
}
```

the problem I have is, after I type 1 as:

```
if(x == 1|)   // '|' is the cursor
```

I have to press left arrow key `->` to get out of the parentheses `)` then type bracket. Since arrow key `->` is quite far from the most used keys, it really slows me down when I move my finger that far to access the arrow key and then move my finger back, is it quick way/shortcut to get out of parentheses in VS Code?

Comment: @paxdiablo to ensure 120WPM typing speed, you can't press arrow key too many times, the tab out plugin in the answer is exactly what I want, and since this plugin exists, I believe many people had the same issues as I had

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could type the closing bracket or try an extension like tabout
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=albert.TabOut

Comment: @amjad, that's fine if you're entering `1` from the top row (since the TAB key is close by). What happens when you're entering `9`, or using the numeric keypad?

Comment: @paxdiablo do you do  touch typing? if you do then you know typing 9 is like typing a letter. I don't use keyboard with numeric keypad(numeric keypad is for general users not for programmers in my option).

Comment: I don't do touch typing no, I prefer to type at a speed where my fingers aren't outpacing my brain :-)

Comment: @poproar could you have a look at this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63788122/is-it-a-way-shortcut-plugin-so-that-the-cursor-will-be-idented-nicely-when-you-c